# How to merge unallocated disk space in a device in another device?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partition, devices, merge

when I'm doing "fdisk -l" we can see :

```
Device           Start       End   Sectors  Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1    2048   1050623   1048576  512M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2 1050624 500117503 499066880  238G Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/sda: 931,53 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: ST1000LX015-1U71
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 36C0FEFE-3500-445E-84F1-88E0D80BC401
```

I would like to "put" the 931,53 GiB of /dev/sda in the "/home" of the partition /dev/nvme0n1p2

How can I perform this?

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Comment: You cannot. Different physical devices are different physical devices. There are some device modules that will allow you to create a virtual disk out of different disks, so you could merge the 238 GB on nvme0n1p2 with a newly created 930 GB partition /dev/sda1 and "see" a single /dev/md0, 1168 GB in size. But you need to reformat both partitions and mess with the kernel (more so, if you want to be able to boot from the virtual device. Check out `md` and LVM.

Comment: You might find this article useful: https://www.linuxadictos.com/en/lvm-fusionar-discos-duros-como-si-solo-fuesen-uno.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I will give up because do not want to reformat my /dev/nvme0n1p2

Comment: However, you might be able to move parts of your system on the Seagate disk. Check out which is larger - /var, /home, /opt and so on - and you should be able to first *copy*, say, /var to /dev/sda1; then rename the old /var to /old-var and mount /dev/sda1 on /var by editing /etc/fstab. If everything works after a reboot (it should), delete /old-var and enjoy the free space on /dev/nvme0n1p2 (also, the new /var can now grow up to 960 GB!).